# Is there any way to activate django admin site without admin.py

Tags: python, django

I have many apps and i want to activate the admin for all the models in my all apps.

I remember few months one of my friend did something that enables the admin site without any admin.py file

he did something in `settings.py` files with `INSTALLED_APPS` and all of the apps showed in the admin section

I am now not able to find that. Any one??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend probably did something like...

```
from django.db.models import get_models

for model in get_models():
    admin.site.register(model)
```

In one of his admin.py files.

I dunno, I'd only do this to test stuff. It's a bit too magical. Remember you'll have to explicitly `unregister` any models you may want to register again.

Comment: i just remember one line from his function `autoregister(*settings.INSTALLED_APPS)`. i don't know what was that function. that was in urls.py file not in nay admin.py file

Comment: something less efficient than what I posted above. INSTALLED_APPS contains strings, so you'd have to resolve model classes... get_models() actually returns model classes.

Or perhaps he did something that actually writes physical python files if they don't exist.

Comment: Does it return models from all the installed apps with your answer

Comment: thanks buddy. i will do that. i don't understood ur unregister things.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the instructions in the docs. [They describe how to activate the django admin site here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#activate-the-admin-site). You need to modify `urls.py`. That's it.

There are even comments in that file that tell you which three lines to uncomment.

Comment: You didn't get. i know that one but for that i have to write autoregister in admin.py file. but i don't want that to write for all my apps

Comment: You always have to call `admin.site.register(YouModel)` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you do include an `admin.py` in your apps because it is the Django convention and that some explicitness in what you trying to achieve is a good thing; the solution I use is the following default `admin.py` template for all new apps I start:

```
# Auto registers any new models with the admin, eventually you will want a tailored admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
current_app = models.get_app(__package__) 
for model in models.get_models(current_app):
    admin.site.register(model, admin.ModelAdmin)
```